# Pouchdb design view not properly evaluated

Tags: pouchdb

I'm writting a smal sync adaptor for [tiddlywiki](http://tiddlywiki.com) using pouchdb as a library. I have experimented with couchdb about same idea successfully, and I though that pouchdb should be very similar, but better.

Everything is working fine except one particular view of the main design document. I just copied the view that I'm using at couchdb which is working great, but I'm getting an stupid error: fields is not defined. Which is obviously defined! Here is my view code:

```
function (doc) {
        fields = {};
        for(var field in doc.fields ){
            //text should not be included, neither title. We also avoid to send too long fields
         if( ['text','title'].indexOf(field) === -1 && doc.fields[field].length < 1024){
            fields[field] = doc.fields[field];
         }
        }
        fields.revision = doc._rev; //required for proper sync 
    emit(doc._id,fields);
}
```

As you can see, the first thing that I'm doing is to define the fields. I tried adding `var fields` and the result is the same. This is driving me crazy. If I want this to work, I have to join everything in the same line. My goal is to externalize this function to a text document to be able to easily edit it, so I can do something like this:

```
var My_view=DoWatheverToGetTheText();
var design_document = {
  '_id': '_design/tw',
  'views': {
    'skinny-tiddlers': {
      'map': My_view
    }}
  };
```

I tried and I'm getting exactly the same error. I don't want this to be hardcoded into my aplication, I want it to be modular. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This works properly on Firefox, so seems to be a Chrome problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I found the solution myself.

The way I did it was, first of all, splitting the design document in two files. One with just the design document definition, without the map function but with an empty property on its place. It is very important to make sure this document is valid JSON, that was one of my problems.

```
{"_id": "_design/TiddlyPouch",
  "views": {
    "someView": {
      "map": ""
    }},
    "filters": {
      "tiddlers" : ""
}
  }
```

Then I wrote the map function (just the function without name) to a different file. It looks like this:

```
function(doc){
var fields = {};  
for(var field in doc.fields ){ 
    if( ['text','title'].indexOf(field) === -1){
        fields[field] = doc.fields[field];
    }
}
fields.revision = doc._rev;
emit(doc._id,fields);
 }
```

To make all them fit, I first evaluated the design document to get a design object. Then, I fetched the function as plain text and I joined it, without any carriage return. Basically I make it one line. Then all you have to do is to put that function which is plain text as a the value of the map property:

```
stringContainingFunction = functiontext.replace(/\r?\n/,' ');
designDocument.views.someView.map = stringContainingFunction;
```

After that, I just pushed the object to pouchdb, and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

> As you can see, the first thing that I'm doing is to define the fields.

A guess: You are missing the var keyword for `fields = {};`. This will cause a reference error when running javascript in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Converting_mistakes_into_errors).